# Check if file exists in s3 using ls and wildcard

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

Seems so simple, but not getting the syntax right.  I want to know if a file exists in my s3 bucket using wildcards.  Something like

```
aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/folder/*myfile*
```

The goal is to see if a file called `2016_myfile.txt` or a file called `2011_myfile.csv` exists within this bucket.

If I run the command, it doesn't return anything even though I know this file exists there.

Comment: Very inefficient, but why not do something like "aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/folder/ | grep myfile" ?

That is, if you insist on using the CLI. A python script using Boto would be much more efficient, though it's not a single line command.

Comment: @GilAdirim Actually that would work as well. I was just surprised that the aws-cli didn't provide something like this and thought I was missing something

Comment: @GilAdirim I've been looking at Boto and I don't see how it supports wildcards either, do you have a pointer you could provide?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

(re-drafted from comment as it appears this answered the question)

I myself tried, and failed to use wildcards in the aws-cli, and according to the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/), this is not currently supported.
Simplest (though least efficient) solution would be to use grep:

```
aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/folder/ | grep myfile
```

Alternatively, you could write a short python/other script to do this more efficiently (but not in a single command)

Comment: This will produce inaccurate results if you have more than 1000 objects in the bucket.

Comment: @DaveYarwood, I don't think that's true. I think you're talking about the _page-size_ limit, which isn't relevant here.

Comment: won't this transfert all filenames to your local machine first?

Answer (score 71):

`aws s3 ls` does not support globs, but sync **does** and has a dry run mode. So if you do this (from an empty directory) you should get the results you want:

```
aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket . --exclude "*" --include "folder/*myfile*" --dryrun
```

It will produce lines like this for matching files:

```
(dryrun) download s3://my-bucket/folder/myfile.txt to folder/myfile.txt
(dryrun) download s3://my-bucket/folder/_myfile-foo.xml to folder/_myfile-foo.xml
```

Comment: I just tried this, and it worked `aws s3 sync --exclude '*' --include '*.DS_Store' s3://mybucket ./` thank you for that post! +1

Comment: This is so much better that top answer - simply because if you use `aws s3 ls` piped to `grep`  you are limited to 1000 results in a page so if your bucket has more than 1000 items you'll not get reliable results

Comment: This isn't  a solution if you want the file timestamp or size that you get with `aws s3 ls`

Comment: You can even use `aws s3 rm` instead of `aws s3 sync` and then it doesn't matter where you run it from :)

Answer (score 15):

S3 doesn't support wildcard listing. You need to list all the files and grep it.

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/folder --recursive
```

Above command will give the list of files under your folder, it searches the files inside the folder as well. Just grep your file name

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/folder --recursive |grep filename
```

Suppose if you want to find multiple files, create a regular expression of those and grep it.

Comment: This will produce inaccurate results if you have more than 1000 objects in the bucket.

Comment: @DaveYarwood:  could you specify why?  I know these operations are not nearly as reliable as analogous filesystem ones, but a quick search didn't turn up much for me.

Comment: IIRC, there is a limit of 1000 on the number of items that `aws s3 ls` will return.

Comment: @DaveYarwood, do you mean there is a *page-size* limit of 1000, because `aws s3 ls` will clearly return more than 1000 values (as I verified just now). I understand the docs to mean that the page limit is **per API call** happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows User:

```
aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/folder/ | findstr myfile
```

Answer (score 1):

*2022 Update:*

You can use this supported with aws s3 with the `--dry-run` option:

```
aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket . --include "folder/*myfile*" --exclude "*" --dryrun
```

Alternatively,

s3cmd also works for me with grep.

```
s3cmd ls --recursive s3://mybucket/folder/folder2 | grep filename
```