# Delete Multiple Subfolders in S3 Bucket using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to delete multiple subfolders in S3 using the AWS CLI? There's `include and exclude` command specified in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/rm.html) but I think it's for the S3 Items and not for folders?

Tried this command but its not working `aws s3 rm s3://bucketname/*/*/foldertodelete --recursive`

```
Sample folder structure:

bucketname/folder/subfolder/itemfolder
bucketname/folder/subfolder/foldertodelete

bucketname/anotherfolder/subfolder/itemfolder
bucketname/anotherfolder/subfolder/foldertodelete

bucketname/andanotherfolder/andsubfolder/itemfolder
bucketname/andanotherfolder/andsubfolder/foldertodelete
```

Did I missed something? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: S3 API doesn't support wildcard characters... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857802/check-if-file-exists-in-s3-using-ls-and-wildcard

Comment: @marekful seems so. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: (**Make sure you create a backup before running the command to avoid any unexpected result**)

`aws s3 rm s3://bucketname/ --exclude "*" --include "*foldertodelete/*" --recursive`

Wildcard is not supported in the command's path argument.

Comment: hmm strange because I've tested it and it seems to be working for me. Did you use `--include "*foldertodelete/*"` because I had updated it. You need to add * before `foldertodelete`

Comment: Now it works. My bad, I input a non-existing folder. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple `--include`s:

`aws s3 rm s3://bucket --recursive --include "folder1/*" --include "foo/folder2/*"`

...as well as multiple `--exclude`s.

Note: the order of `--include` and `--exclude` matters, they are applied in order. Also default is `--include "*"` if nothing given.